# Laravel- newly inserted eloquent record breaks id sequence

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models, news and editorials. When I seed the db with 50 news and 4 editorials the id of the news and editorials are in sequential order i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc. But after I insert either a news or editorial through the user form the next news id is set to 55, which should be 51. and when adding editorial  the next id is 56 when that should 5 since the last editorial id is 4. I am struggling to figure out what causing this strange problem.

News Seeder

```php
class NewsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Models\News::class,50)->create()->each(
            function($news){
                $faker = Faker::create();

                //---------create one category------------
                $category_array =['Women & Children','Minority', 'Free Speech', 'Democracy'];
                $randomCategory = array_rand($category_array);
                $category= new Category();
                $category->description = $category_array[$randomCategory];
                $category->save();

                $news->category()->associate($category);

                //---------create multiple tags -----------
                    $randomCounter = rand(1,3);
                    $tag_array =['Politics','Environment','Hate Speech', 'Weather'];
                    for ($i=0; $i<$randomCounter ; $i++) {
                        $tag = new Tag();
                        $tag->description = $tag_array[$i];
                        $news->tags()->save($tag);

                    }//end for
                //------- create multiple tags-------------

                //------- create multiple comments for this news------------
                    $randomCounter= rand(1,10);
                    for ($i=0; $i<$randomCounter ; $i++) {
                        $comment                = new Comment();
                        $comment->user_name     = $faker->name();
                        $comment->email         = $faker->safeEmail();
                        $comment->title         = $faker->sentence(rand(2,3));
                        $comment->content       = $faker->paragraph(rand(10,15));
                        $comment->status          ='Approved';
                        $comment->news_id       =$news->id;
                        //$comment->save();

                        $news->comments()->save($comment);

                    }//end for
            }//end inner function
        );
    }
}
```

Editorial Seeder

```php
class EditorialTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Models\Editorial::class,4)->create()->each(
            function($editorial){
                $faker = Faker::create();

                //---------create one category------------
                $category_array =['Women & Children','Minority', 'Free Speech', 'Democracy'];
                $randomCategory = array_rand($category_array);
                $category= new Category();
                $category->description = $category_array[$randomCategory];
                $category->save();

                $editorial->category()->associate($category);

                //---------create multiple tags -----------
                    $randomCounter = rand(1,3);
                    $tag_array =['Politics','Environment','Hate Speech', 'Weather'];;
                    for ($i=0; $i<$randomCounter ; $i++) {
                        $tag = new Tag();
                        $tag->description = $tag_array[$i];
                        $editorial->tags()->save($tag);

                    }//end for
                //------- create multiple tags-------------

                //------- create multiple comments for this news------------
                    $randomCounter= rand(1,10);
                    for ($i=0; $i<$randomCounter ; $i++) {
                        $comment                = new Comment();
                        $comment->user_name     = $faker->name();
                        $comment->email         = $faker->safeEmail();
                        $comment->title         = $faker->sentence(rand(2,3));
                        $comment->content       = $faker->paragraph(rand(10,15));
                        $comment->status          ='Approved';
                        $comment->editorial_id       =$editorial->id;

                        $editorial->comments()->save($comment);

                }//end for
            }
        );
    }
}
```

News controller save method

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validate the data
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'news_title' => 'required|min:20|max:150',
        'news_short_desc' => 'required|max:250|min:10',
        'news_story' => 'required|max:2500|min:10',
    ]);

    //if validation fails laravel will automatically redirect to previous page
    $validator->validate();

    //validation successful proceed with saving the record
    //and also add record to linked/ junction tables
    $news = new News;
    $news->title = $request->news_title;
    $news->short_desc = $request->news_short_desc;
    $news->story = $request->news_story;
    $news->image_path = url('/') . $request->filepath;

    if ($request->has('is_featured')) {
        $news->is_featured = 'Y';
    } else {
        $news->is_featured = 'N';
    }

    //check dropdown inputs
    $category = new Category();

    switch ($request->input('news_category')) {
        case 'w':
            //$news->category_id= 1;
            $category->description = 'Women & Children';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $news->category()->associate($category);
            break;

        case 'm':
            //$news->category_id= 2;
            $category->description = 'Minority';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $news->category()->associate($category);
            break;

        case 'f':
            //$news->category_id= 3;
            $category->description = 'Free Speech';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $news->category()->associate($category);
            break;

        case 'd':
            // $news->category_id= 4;
            $category->description = 'Democracy';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $news->category()->associate($category);
            break;
    } //end switch

    $news->posted_by = auth('admin')->user()->name;

    $news->save();

    //create Tags
    $tag_array = LogicHelper::getTagList();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($tag_array); $i++) {
        if (($request->has('tag_' . ($i + 1)))) {
            $tag = new Tag();
            //create new tag
            $tag->description = $tag_array[$i];
            // $tag->save();
            $news->tags()->save($tag);
        } //end if
    }//end for

    Session::flash('add_success', 'News Added Successfully!');
    return redirect()->route('add.news');
}//end method
```

Editorial save method

```php
public function save(Request $request){
    //validate the data
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|min:20|max:150',
        'short_desc' => 'required|max:190|min:10',
        'content' => 'required|max:2500|min:10',

    ]);

    //if validation fails laravel will automatically redirect to previous page
    $validator->validate();
    //check if at least one image exists!

    //validation successful proceed with saving the record
    //and also add record to linked/ junction tables
    $editorial = new Editorial();
    $editorial->title= $request->title;
    $editorial->short_description= $request->short_desc;
    $editorial->content= $request->content;
    //check dropdown inputs
    $category = new Category();

    switch ($request->input('category')) {
        case 'w':
            //$editorial->category_id= 1;
            $category->description = 'Women & Children';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $editorial->category()->associate($category);
            break;

        case 'm':
            // $editorial->category_id= 2;
            $category->description = 'Minority';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $editorial->category()->associate($category);
            break;

        case 'f':
            //$editorial->category_id= 3;
            $category->description = 'Free Speech';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $editorial->category()->associate($category);
            break;

        case 'd':
            //$editorial->category_id= 4;
            $category->description = 'Democracy';
            $category->save();
            //add record to link table
            $editorial->category()->associate($category);
            break;
    }//end switch

    $editorial->image_path= url('/').$request->filepath;

    $editorial->posted_by= auth('admin')->user()->name;

    $editorial->save();

    Session::flash('add_success','Editorial Created Successfully!');
    return redirect()->route('add.editorial');

}//end method
```

Comment: I suggest you login to your database and view the records in the table. Find out whats taking the IDs within 50 - 55

Comment: I had look at the db and found that the skipped ids i.e. 51-54 are in the category table although there is no news for those categories